# Java implements Runnable: Cannot resolve Symbol 'start'

Tags: java, runnable

I stripped everything out to see if I could narrow down my problem and figure it out but I'm embarrassed to say I'm still stumped. Can someone please explain to me why my IDE cannot resolve 'start'? I'm sure it's a stupid mistake :(

```
public class main {

    Thread messageThread = new Thread(new MessageLoop());
    messageThread.start();

    class MessageLoop implements Runnable {

        public void run(){
            //Do stuff here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The code `MessageThread.start()` is not placed in a method block or constructor, is in the class's body.

Comment: You're trying to execute a statement outside of functional context (ie, a method)

Comment: When should that line execute? Why do you think so?

Comment: put `MessageThread.start();` in your psvm

Answer (score 1):

Instead of defining your class in your method body. Java variable names start with a lower case letter by convention. Comments start with `//` not `\\`. I think you wanted something like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Thread messageThread = new Thread(new MessageLoop());
    messageThread.start();
}

static class MessageLoop implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        // Do stuff here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Use following approaches.**

**Approach1**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


            Thread MessageThread = new Thread(new MessageLoop());
            MessageThread.start();

}

     static class MessageLoop implements Runnable {

            public void run(){
               System.out.println("helllo");
            }
        }
```

**Approach 2**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
            Thread MessageThread2 = new Thread(new Runnable(){
                 public void run(){
                      System.out.println("helllo2");
                   }    
            });
            MessageThread2.start();
}
```